# apache hive loads null values instead of intergers

Tags: apache, hive

I am new to apache hive and was running queries on sample data which is saved in a csv file as below:

```
0195153448;"Classical Mythology";"Mark P. O. Morford";"2002";"Oxford University Press";"//images.amazon.com/images/P/0195153448.01.THUMBZZZ.jpg";"http://images.amazon.com/images/P/0195153448.01.MZZZZZZZ.jpg";"images.amazon.com/images/P/0195153448.01.LZZZZZZZ.jpg"
```

and the table which i created is of form

```
hive> describe book;
OK
isbn                    bigint                                      
title                   string                                      
author                  string                                      
year                    string                                      
publ                    string                                      
img1                    string                                      
img2                    string                                      
img3                    string                                      
Time taken: 0.085 seconds, Fetched: 8 row(s)
```

and the script which I used to create the table is:

```
create table book(isbn int,title string,author string, year string,publ string,img1 string,img2 string,img3 string) row format delimited fields terminated by '\;' lines terminated by '\n' location 'path';
```

When I try to retrieve the data from the table by using the following query:

```
select *from book limit 1;
```

I get the following result:

```
NULL    "Classical Mythology"   "Mark P. O. Morford"    "2002"  "Oxford University Press"   "http://images.amazon.com/images/P/0195153448.01.THUMBZZZ.jpg"  "images.amazon.com/images/P/0195153448.01.MZZZZZZZ.jpg" "images.amazon.com/images/P/0195153448.01.LZZZZZZZ.jpg"
```

Even though I specify the first column type as int or bigint the data into the table is getting loaded as NULL.

I tried searching on the internet and could figure out that I have to specify the row delimiter. I used that too but no change in the data from the table.

Is there anything that I am making a mistake... Please help.

Comment: There is no issue with table create and select statements , I do get correct values after select.  Which hive version you have ?, I have tested this on Hive 1.2.1.2.3.4.29

Comment: Thanks for the reply syadav.. i am using Hive 2.1.0 version.

Comment: Just a guess...Try to create table as string and then select cast(isbn as int) as isbn.  Maybe the problem is leading zeroes.